# Address of Operator for buffer in C

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am reading the book "Hacking:Art of Exploitation",I am struggling to understand the following code:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
        int value = 5; 
        char buffer_one[8],buffer_two[8]; 
        strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); /* Put "one" into buffer_one. */ 
        strcpy(buffer_two, "two"); /* Put "two" intobuffer_two. */ 
        printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains\'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two); 
        printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one); 
        printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
```

What I am not able to understand is, in first 2 printf statements we are not using address of operator but the output is giving the memory address and for integer we are providing the address to (&) operator. I have checked with gdb, I am obtaining the same results if I use &buffer_two and &buffer_one but when I am I am removing address of operator before value in last printf statement, the output I get is 0x5.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you are about to step from novice to experienced realm.  :-)

When you define an array, like `char buffer_one[8]`, the name `buffer_one` is a label standing for the address of the array. The label has no associated address with it, and compilers chose to implement `&buffer_one` to give the same result as without the `&`.

Not so for a value which is not an array, like `value`. `value` holds a value, and `&value` gives you the address of the variable `value`.

Hope this clarifies things.

BTW, the same goes to function pointers. We all learned that a function pointer is used like so: `(*func_ptr)()` to call the function it points to, but it works like this too: `func_ptr()`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, when we assign an array, compiler assigns a memory for it, and later the buffer value is placed in it. If that is the case, it is only format strings that identifies if memory address is called for using %p or string/value is called using %s?

Comment: Well, it is not that the format string identifies the memory type. It is less clever than that. The format string forces treating the memory as a pointer (if %p) or as an array of chars (if %s).

Answer (score 0):

> In case of arrays, the array name itself corresponds to the first element of the array (array[0]) which is not the case with intergers/float variables. That's why you'll get the same output even if you put '&' operator with arrays.

This is similar how we handle reading a string and integer value from stdin. There we don't need & operator with strings in scanf.

```
int main(void)
{
     char str[50];
     int n;
     printf("Enter a string and a number\n");
     scanf("%s %d", str, &n);
     printf("string entered: %s, number: = %d", str, n );
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to understand is, in first to printf statements %p prints out the memory address without  & and it works, in third printf if I don't use address of operator, it doesn't work.

Comment: That's what above illustration iterates. To get the address of int/float variable you have to use '&' operator. In case of array, array name itself corresponds to the location of the first element of the array, that's why without even using '&' operator, you're getting the desired result. Hope I'm clear this time!!